# How to use letsencrypt.org SSL on a Jelastic Java Environment

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssh, https, jelastic

Hi I have deployed a Java EE 7 Web Application on Jelastic, Java 8 ,Glassfish 4.1 and nginx as the load balancer
, Use my custom domain name `derbyware.com`, now I want to add SSL. I searched and found this guys **letsencrypt.org** . and I would like to use their service. I've read [ssh gate overview](http://docs.jelastic.com/ssh-gate) & [custom ssl](https://docs.jelastic.com/custom-ssl), and now, using PuTTY, I have access for my environment.

```
Please select the required container provisioned for the 'env-7*****.phx.enscaled.us' environment.
      Node name                               nodeid  LAN IP             Alias
   0. Back
   1. Refresh
   2. Glassfish-4.1                           1***4   10.1***
   3. Nginx-1.10.1 (Load Balancer)            1**3   10.1***

Enter [0-3]: 3
Last login: Tue Jul  4 17:22:35 UTC 2017
nginx@node****-env-**** ~ $
```

and on [certbot website](https://certbot.eff.org/#sharedhost-nginx), It does **NOT** say anything on how to proced, What Should I do now? what are the commands that need to be executed using ssh??

if this not the right way to do it please tell what should I do to add SSL

Comment: Please check add-ons in the Jelastic marketplace / buttons to control your node. You can add let's encrypt in just a few clicks there (no need for SSH and manual install of certbot). Also I see you're a Layershift customer, so please contact our support team if you need further help!

Comment: @Damien-Layershift , Ok, I tried to install it on nginx but it says "An unknown error has occurred. Please try again later. We apologize for the inconvenience." . Should I select Glassfish server Node??

Comment: Please contact support for help with this